# Live Stream Time Shifting from Android TV

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I am implementing an app that transmits Live Streaming to a TV using android's tv input framework.

And currently, it is in the form of downloading adaptive streaming from my Streaming Server.

In this situation, I am trying to implement TimeShift, but due to the nature of Live Stream, where the start and end are not fixed, shifting the time does not work.
So, while the channel is playing, one side downloads the file to the external storage, reads the file, and plays it with ExoPlayer.

ExoPlayer plays only about 8-9 seconds of video received during the brief delay that exists in the beginning.

Is there any way to dynamically update ExoPlayer's files?

Comment: To me it sounds like your manifest to play anything at all isn't specifying that it's a live stream appropriately, so exoplayer is not looking for further media files beyond the first chunk. 

What does the manifest look like that you're serving to exoplayer?

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your help chris, I kind of understood what you were talking about. As you said, I know that exoplayer only plays the first chunk. As an analogy, I want to dynamically increase the length of a chunk. I have implemented the part about the manifest in case of receiving the Stream of SmoothStream and Hls, but the largest part of the current stream server is the MPEG-TS file. So, I couldn't superficially confirm the part that serves the Manifest file.

Comment: You can't really dynamically update the chunk size. This is how the video data is packaged at the back end before it event reaches you. If I were you, I'd look at adding my content url's into the exoplayer demo app and getting it to run in there. If you manage that then it should be enough of a reference to update your own code. And if not, you have a sample that will give the exoplayer contributors a chance to help you out. clone this to get started. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: I know what you're talking about. If so, I am in a situation where I cannot dynamically update the chunk file, and the company I belong to requires a TimeShifting function for Live Streaming. There are also several other products in the industry that can do this. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: I don't know how to go about updating the video data packaging to enable this, sorry. Everytime I've implemented something like this, it's been packaged in a way that allows me to collect the video data prepared specifically for this feature.

Comment: it's okay. You have already been of great help to me. Inspired by your opinion that the chunk itself does not increase, I implemented this by using MergingDataSource in ExoPlayer 2 to connect media sources divided into the size I want.